# I have a problem integrating the calculateOrderAmount using stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate stripe into my Website. I am trying to figure out how to replace the constant with a calculation of the order's amount. So let's say my item cost $85.00 with tax it's $90.31 how would I place that into code?

**I have provided my code below:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
// This is your test secret API key.
const stripe = require("stripe")('sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXX');

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
    
  return 1400;
};

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { items } = req.body;

  // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
    currency: "usd",
    automatic_payment_methods: {
      enabled: true,
    },
  });

  res.send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log("Node server listening on port 4242!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `items` array is passed in the request, you can use that to determine the price of each item, then calculate the total and tax accordingly.

For example, `items` may contain `item_id` and `quantity` such as:

```
[
  {
    item_id: 'id_123',
    quantity: 1,
  },
  {
    item_id: 'id_456',
    quantity: 2,
  }
]
```

In your database, you can store the unit price of item ID:

| item_id | unit_price (minor unit) |
| --- | --- |
| id_123 | 500 |
| id_456 | 1500 |

Then you can determine the unit price from the item ID in your database and calculate from there:

```
totalItemAmount = (500 * 1 + 1500 * 2) = 3500
totalTax = 3500 * 0.10 = 350 // assuming tax is 10%
total = totalItemAmount + totalTax // which is 3500 + 350 = 3850
```