# Having a problem with setting up my server and calculateOrderAmount using stripe quick set up

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate stripe into my Website. I am trying to figure out how to replace the constant with a calculation of the order's amount. So let's say my item cost $85.00 with tax it's $90.31 how would I place that into code? Also after running "npm start" I continue to get an error for the placement of my values.

**I have provided my code below:**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    // This is your test secret API key.
    const stripe = require("stripe")('sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXX');
    
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.use(express.json());
    
    const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
       [
    {
      item_id: 'price_XXXXXX',
      quantity: 5,
    },
    {
      item_id: 'price_XXXXXX',
      quantity: 5,
    },
    {
      item_id: 'pprice_XXXXXX',
      quantity: 5,
    },
    {
      item_id: 'price_XXXXXX',
      quantity: 5,
    },
  ]

  totalItemAmount = (425 * 4) = 1700
  totalTax = (1700 * 0.0625) = 106.25 
  total = totalItemAmount + totalTax 
  
  return 1400;
    };
    
    app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
      const { items } = req.body;
    
      // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
      const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
        currency: "usd",
        automatic_payment_methods: {
          enabled: true,
        },
      });
    
      res.send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
      });
    });
    
    app.listen(4242, () => console.log("Node server listening on port 4242!"));
```

**Terminal Results**

```
Royces-MacBook-Air:Kingdom Website  roycewilliams$ npm start

> start
> node server.js

/Volumes/REVITAL/REVITAL/In Progress/Kingdom Website/Kingdom Website /server.js:29
  totalItemAmount = (425 * 4) = 1700
                    ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
Royces-MacBook-Air:Kingdom Website  roycewilliams$
```

Comment: The the variable is not declared and you don't have to calculate the outcome when using it. The code will compute for you. For example, `const totalItemAmount = 425 * 4` in actual cold. In my [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74229521/i-have-a-problem-integrating-the-calculateorderamount-using-stripe/74229700#74229700) in another post, it just shows how calculation works and it's not actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code please check it.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
// This is your test secret API key.
const stripe = require("stripe")('sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXX');
const _ = require("lodash"); // install lodash depedancy 
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
    // Assume this is your items objects like this
    items = [
        {
            item_id: 'price_XXXXXX',
            quantity: 5,
            price: 12

        },
        {
            item_id: 'price_XXXXXX',
            quantity: 5,
            price: 120
        },
        {
            item_id: 'pprice_XXXXXX',
            quantity: 5,
            price: 10
        },
        {
            item_id: 'price_XXXXXX',
            quantity: 5,
            price: 100
        },
    ];

    const totalItemAmount = _.reduce(items, function (value, data) {
        return (data.price * data.quantity) + value;
    }, 0);
    const totalTax = (totalItemAmount * 0.18); // assuming tax is 18%
    const total = totalItemAmount + totalTax;

    return total;
};

app.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
    const { items } = req.body;

    // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
        currency: "usd",
        automatic_payment_methods: {
            enabled: true,
        },
    });

    res.send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log("Node server listening on port 4242!"));
```